# django wsgi with apache2 configuration gives page not found 404

Tags: python, django, apache, apache2

For assumption here

`testsite.com` which is my php application and

`testsite.com/project` is python-django application

I have following settings in my apache site config file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/site.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
                ServerAdmin webmaster@testsite.com
                ServerName testsite.com
                DocumentRoot /var/www/html

                WSGIDaemonProcess test python-path=/var/www/html/projectenv/test-project python-home=/var/www/html/projectenv
                WSGIProcessGroup test
                WSGIScriptAlias /project /var/www/html/projectenv/test-project/test-project/wsgi.py


                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**NOTE: I have to keep WSGIScriptAlias as /project since only for this url my django project should work.**

But when I hit `testsite.com/project` its giving following error

```
Page not found (404)
Using the URLconf defined in test-project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
project/
The empty path didn't match any of these.
```

Here is my project url structure

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('projectapp.urls'))
]
```

projectapp/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('project/', views.home, name='project'),
]
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_filters',
    'projectapp',

]
```

Please suggest solution that when I hit this url `testsite.com/project` it should go through my defined django app and render the page which is linked to this view, Its observed that wsgi is not able to pass through the django project structure and due to which its not identifying the url given in app. Or may be its not able to find the app structure.

What should I change inorder to make this work, please suggest

Comment: If you use `testsite.com/project` it will look for `project` within the `testsite.com` directory, which won't exist as its a different project all together. You're better off using `project` as a subdomain. I.e. `project.testsite.com`

Comment: @Anthony: testsite.com is not the directory. Is my website domain, So whenever this url hits it goes through the document root which is mentioned in virtualhost, I would suggest please go through my project structure carefully in ```site.conf``` file  And I want to use the url ```/project``` to render my django application. So please suggest accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution finally, its bit of conceptual

As `WSGIScriptAlias` is mentioned above as `/project`, which means for wsgi the project scope will only be limited to `/project` directory, and rest of other apps which are outside of `/project` directory will not be accessible by wsgi

Thats why it was giving `Page not found (404)`

**Hence this is what it expects as follows**

```
WSGIScriptAlias /test-project /var/www/html/projectenv/test-project/test-project/wsgi.py
```

So now all the app urls which are inside `/test-project` becomes accessible to wsgi

I can now access my django project url as `testsite.com/test-project/project` and alongside `testsite.com` which is my php application, both are running absolutely fine.

**So lesson here is, wsgi always requires the main project directory path to traverse through the all the apps inside it, though its mentioned in django official documentation but we generally miss this concept. Hope this answer will help you who struggling with same issue!**